Convergence in $L^1$ for partial sums of random variables
I'm working on some practice problems for modes of convergence of random variables, and realized midway through that I am struggling a lot on $L^1$ convergence. Consider, for example, the sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = -1) = 1/2$. Then consider the sequence $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j/j$. Does $S_n$ converge in $L^1$?
To answer this question, my initial approach was as follows: write out and simplify the expectation as:
$$\mathbb{E}(|S_n-S|) = \mathbb{E}\bigg(\bigg|\sum_{j=1}^nX_j/j - \sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j/j\bigg|\bigg) = \mathbb{E}\bigg(\bigg|\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty X_j/j\bigg|\bigg)$$
This is where I run into a problem. The triangle inequality can't help me here because using it leads to $\mathbb{E}(|S_n-S|)\leq\infty$, which isn't informative. Jensen's inequality leads to $\mathbb{E}(|S_n-S|)\geq 0$, which is similarly uninformative.
How do I approach $L^1$ converge problems such as this? Is there a single generalizable technique that I can use to establish $L^1$ convergence for sums such as this? Some other problems that I ran into trouble with for this same reason are when $X_n$ are random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1/\sqrt{n}) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = -1/\sqrt{n})=1/2$, and $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^nX_j$, or when $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1/n) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = -1/n) = 1/2$. For these, I also struggle to establish whether the sequence is $L^1$ convergent.

Are you familiar with martingale theory? It can be proved that $S_n$ is a $L^2$-bounded martingale, hence uniformly integrable with convergence a.s and in $L^1$. But anyway, you can bound the square $E(|S_m-S|)^2 \leq E(|S_m-S|^2) \leq \sum_{j=n+1} j^{-2}  \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$ assuming $(X_n) $ are iid

I see what you're saying - my main difficulty with dealing with $L^1$ convergence was the fact that $S_n$ could potentially be negative, and the absolute value function is difficult to bound correctly, but when dealing with $L^2$ convergence I don't have to worry about this. I didn't think of the martingale approach (you can use Kolmogorov's Convergence Criterion to show that $S_n$ converges almost surely).

So does my comment help you solve the problem? Or do you have other questions? I just wanted to advertise the famous martingale theory (which I thought you haven't been familiar with), the above bound can also be obtained with the hypothesis that $E[X_iX_j]=0$

Yes, it does! I know how the expansion of $(\sum_{j=1}^n j)^2$ goes. The random variables $X_j$ are i.i.d. so everything works out.

As stated in LNT's comment, the most straightforward approach is to deal with $L^2$ convergence first. Then our calculations work out as:
$$\mathbb{E}\Bigg(\bigg(\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty X_j/j\bigg)^2\Bigg) = \mathbb{E}\bigg(\sum_{j = n+1}^\infty X_j^2/j^2 + 2\sum_{i<j}^\infty \frac{X_iX_j}{j^2}\bigg) = \mathbb{E}\bigg(\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty X_j^2/j^2\bigg) = \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty 1/j^2 \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 0$$
Then we can use the fact that $L^2$ convergence implies $L^1$ convergence, and the problem is solved.
